# Error in script PHP: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /www/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 76

Tags: php, csv

I have this script:

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$file = fopen("plikk.txt", "r") or die("Error");
$i=0;
$data = array();
while(!feof($file)){
    $linia=fgets($file);
    $html = file_get_html($linia);
    $data[$i]['opis']  = $html->find(".editor-content",0)->innertext;
    $data[$i]['foto']  = $html->find("img",13)->src;
}

fclose($file);

$filename = 'users.csv';
$FileHandle = fopen($filename, 'w+') or die("can't open file");

foreach($data as $line){

    fputcsv($FileHandle, $line, ';', '"');

}
fclose($FileHandle);
?>
```

When i start that, i get a 2 errors and script nothing do :

> [Sun Mar 26 18:39:02.773349 2017] [:error] [pid 22066] [client
>   XX.XX.XX.XX:53498] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /www/public_html/simple_html_dom.php
>   on line 76
>
> [Sun Mar 26 18:39:02.773734 2017] [:error] [pid 22066] [client
>   XX.XX.XX.XX:53498] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on boolean in /www/public_html/sko.php on line
>   12

[simple_html_dom.php](http://pastebin.com/sLzj3X5Y)

Comment: your error is in simple_html_dom.php, might help if you post that file too

Comment: Check the value of `$linia`

Comment: @u_mulder In value $linia i have a line with plik.txt

Comment: You'll want to make sure the value of $linea is a valid file name and skip ahead in the loop otherwise using continue;

Comment: @FilipT but is that all? You might have an empty line afterwards

Comment: Fine, if you're 100% sure that `$linia` is __not__ empty and has a name of an existsing file, then...

Comment: But it does look like the error is being thrown in the required file not this one. Could you post the contents of simple_html_dom.php?

Comment: In file plik.txt i had one empty line, and i remove this line script add 1 line to users.csv
@Christopher I added simple_html_dom.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.At the end of the file plik.txt i hade a empty line. Now all its work